# Redirect on NetArt servers don't work

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, redirect

I have a problem on one of the Polish servers (NetArt / Nazwa.pl) with the redirect.

In the htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteRule  !.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|mp4)$|(forum\/|pub\/) index.php [L]
```

For all other servers, it works without a problem here return 500 err. Please help me.
After changing ! to (. +) gets a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

solve the problem on NetArt / nazwa.pl servers.